# How does Spring encode POJOs in GET requests for @ModelAttribute?

Tags: spring-mvc, jamon, modelattribute

I have a Spring MVC controller set up like so:

```
@RequestMapping("activityChart")
public ModelAndView activityChart(
  @RequestParam(required=false, value="parent") String parent,
  @RequestParam(required=false, value="expand") String[] expand,
  @ModelAttribute PaginationArgs paginationargs) throws IOException {

// ... return template renderer

}
```

Where PaginationArgs is a two-field POJO. I want to construct a URL string that includes values for `paginationargs`. It's easy to do for `parent` and `expand` - `activityChart?parent=foo&expand=bar&expand=baz`, but what's the right way to encode a POJO's fields?

JSP takes care of this in Spring with a `<form:form modelAttribute='paginationargs'>` tag, but our project isn't using JSP but Jamon instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the simple case parameter names should be the same as the corresponding field names of the model object. So, if `PaginationArgs` has fields `page` and `size`, it would be like `page=1&size=10`.

In more complex cases Spring can accept parameters whose names are formed as described in [5.4 Bean manipulation and the BeanWrapper](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html#beans-beans).

Comment: Thanks! Having read through the link, what's still not clear to me is what happens if you have two fields in separate @ModelAttribute POJOs with the same name: how would I say paginationargs1.size and paginationargs2.size explicitly?

I've used value="paginationargs1" to set the attribute name, but then writing ?paginationsargs1.size=10 in the URL doesn't seem to work.